# Why doesn't "▷" display in vim?

Tags: unicode, conemu

I'm using ConEmu with WSL. 
I like to have ▷ set as line continuation character:

```
set sbr=▷\ \
```

This is <▷> 9655, Hex 25b7, Octal 22667.
In ConEmu this shows as the square-with-?, and in WSL bash it shows as a blank square.

In MobaXTerm it does display properly. 
I've tried Ubuntu Mono (which I've used with this configuration for years on Linux) and Consolas. In Notepad with Consolas selected, "▷" displays fine. 
[image: Font config in ConEmu]

How should ConEmu be configured?

Comment: You shall use proper font containing this glyph.

Comment: I've tried Ubuntu Mono (which I've used with this configuration for years on Linux) and Consolas. In Notepad with Consolas selected, "▷" displays fine. @Maximus

Comment: How did you try it? Show your font settings.

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: Sadly, Ubunto Mono does not contain that glyph. That's why ConEmu shows you default substitution.

Comment: I think that GDI (which functions ConEmu calls) just can't map your `▷` to any suitable font.

Comment: On my Linux Mint machine, Ubuntu Mono is displaying that glyph just fine ..